# How does Jon Skeet have 176 rep without asking any questions or giving any answers?

Tags: support, reputation

As a devoted [Jon Skeet](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19499#19499) fan I started my day as usual looking at his profile...  and I have noticed this today

[image]

**How does Jon have 176 rep without asking any questions or giving any answers?**

Comment: _I started my day as usual looking at his profile._ really?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19499/38765

Comment: @SagarV: Some (most?) people have a really unhealthy obsession with this one individual. It's actually caused much of his rep inflation, and thus a positive feedback loop of celebrity. SO has become a little like ITV's Love Island.

Comment: I am a great fan of him. FYI @BoundaryImposition

Answer (score 15, accepted):

He has an answer there that was score 6 and accepted and was at least 60 days old at the time the question it was on was deleted, so he keeps the reputation for it according to the [reputation rules](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work).

He also had a second answer there scored 13, but it was a community wiki and didn't affect his reputation in the first place.

Comment: Who dares delete Jon Skeet's answer?! :D

Comment: It was on a question about Google Wave. Not even Jon Skeet could have kept that product from the dust bin.